# fine tune universal-sentence-encoder embeddings

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word-embeddings, topic-models

I am new to NLP and Neural Networks. I want to do topic analysis for a dataset of reviews of our product. I tried to use the `universal-sentence-encoder` along with `top2vec` and they do a good job. However, the similarity score is low most of the time because the combination of words is unique. I want to retrain the model to capture the similarity in my dataset (which is about 40k reviews).

Is there a way to do so? I think this is called *unsupervised fine-tuning*

I am aware of Keras' API to import the transformer as a layer, but I do not how to continue from there.

**Question 1:** What layers or loses could I add to capture similarity between my reviews and outputs vector embedding of the text?

I also read about siamese networks. If I understood correctly, I can add the universal encoder twice as the common network, then add a layer for similarity like [`keras.layers.Dot`](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/dot/).

**Question 2:** If I trained the model on every possible combination of me reviews, can I then use the output of the first embedding layers (with the new weights) as the embedding of text?

**Question 3:** If the answer for question is yes, both embeddings in the siamese networks should be almost identical for the same text. Right?